# Find dataflow source table in .dtsx file

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022, ssdt-bi

I have inherited a corrupt SSIS package. It is unclear what is corrupt about it.
I have build a new solution with a new SSIS project.
Imported the corrupt .dtsx into the new project along with project.params and .connmgr files.
Now I can open the .dtsx but it gives me errors on the connections. (Expected).
In the .dtsx I replaced the values of the old ConnectionManagerID's with the new values found in the project.params.
This works like a charm.
Only the dataflows are giving me a headache.
They have now the proper connection. All of them are using 'Table or view'  as the 'Data access mode'  but the 'Name of the table or view' is empty.
The names of the OLE DB Source components are sufficiently vague that it is not apparent which table or view should be entered into the 'Name of the table or view'.
Can I somehow retrieve this information from the original .dtsx ?

Comment: If you open the .dtsx package in notepad++ (it is all just XML) you can search/find in the text for the data flow task (with the title) then there are details in there for tables source/etc.  It is hard to read but should be there.

Comment: Any idea what tags that would be? because I do see the columns mentioned but cannot find to seem where the table is mentioned

Comment: I dont remember the tag, but if you found the columns, the table should be close to it above that somewhere.  If you still cant find it maybe the columns are unique enough you can use those to search the SQL system tables to find  the table that has those columns in it.

Comment: Try opening a different package which you know the table source of, search for that known table, and you'll know what tags/location to look for for the unknown package.